# Resize Image using canvas and change it to image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with converting a canvas to an image.
I try to resize an image using `drawimage` to canvas, I then take the url of that canvas to the source of another image.

This method is working perfectly in Firefox but when I try it in Chrome, the canvas shows the image but the new image which has the url of that canvas doesn't show up.

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="CanvasNewImage"></canvas><br>
<img id="ResizedImg"><br>

<script type="text/javascript">

 var ImgLink; 
 var CanvasResize = document.getElementById('CanvasNewImage');
 CtxCanvasResize = CanvasResize.getContext('2d');
 CanvasResize.width = 800;
 CanvasResize.height = 800;
 
 var img = document.getElementById('ResizedImg');
 var ResizedImg=new Image();
 
 ResizedImg.src= "5.jpg";
 ResizedImg.onload = function() {
  CtxCanvasResize.drawImage(ResizedImg,0,0,200,200,0,0,200,200);
  ImgLink=CanvasResize.toDataURL("image\jpeg");
  img.src=ImgLink; 

 }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried with "image/png" as the toDataURL ? There are some reports of data to jpeg not working with Chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127441/todataurl-jpeg-not-working-properly-in-chrome-packaged-app

Comment: yes, i did, nothing happen, the same problem